# View not Recognizing the methods of the Model in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm able to successfully load the Model in view but the method inside the model is not recognized by the View. Can anyone point out on where I'm going wrong. I'm using PIP MVC framework http://gilbitron.github.io/PIP/

P.S. I'm new to MVC.

Model.php

```
class Model {

private $connection;

public function __construct()
{
    global $config;

    $this->connection = mysql_pconnect($config['db_host'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password']) or die('MySQL Error: '. mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($config['db_name'], $this->connection);
}

public function execute($qry)
{
    $exec = mysql_query($qry) or die('MySQL Error: '. mysql_error());
    return $exec;
}
```

My Model

```
class Listing_model extends Model {
  public function createNewJob($by) {       
    $result = $this->execute('INSERT INTO job_listings (by_user_id) VALUES ('.$by.')');
    return $result;     
}
}
```

Controller:

```
function create() {     

    $template = $this->loadView('post_jobs_view');
    $model = $this->loadModel('Listing_model'); 
    $template->render();        
}
```

View:

```
if (isset($_POST['savejob'])) {
            $by_user_id = 1111;
            Listing_model::createNewJob($by_user_id);
        }
```

Comment: What framework?  CakePHP?

Comment: @Devon Its called PIP - http://gilbitron.github.io/PIP/

Comment: Okay, no tag for that.  Similar function to cake.  One issue I see is the model function probably shouldn't be called in your view but in your controller.

Comment: How can I do that? My form is in view, I need to find a way to pass the user submitted values to the model so that it is inserted into the DB. Also I'm able to pass the value to the model. The problem is view is not recognizing the execute or query method present in the model

Comment: `$_POST` is still available in your controller and model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you haven't created a static function, so you probably shouldn't be calling it statically.  It looks like PIP loads the model instance into the variable.

```
$model = $this->loadModel('Listing_model'); 
$model->createNewJob($by_user_id);
```

This brings me to the second point, this code seems more fitting for the controller than the view.  You may want to look into how logic should be processed in MVC and what code is appropriate in a view.

Comment: Thanks @devon I'm now able to save the data to model through controller. This is how I modified the view. 

if (isset($_POST['savejob'])) { header('Location:save/'.$_POST['compname']); }

However I'm not able to redirect to the following URL in the controller
$this->redirect('postjobs/create?submitted=true');

Comment: @krish_cloudnow, I don't think that is a very good solution.  Your controller should handle the `isset()` and open a different view if necessary.  You shouldn't redirect in the view like that.

Comment: But in that case how will the controller know the user submitted value?

Comment: @krish_cloudnow, how wouldn't it?  Why would $_POST be available in the view and not the controller?

Comment: I tried to figure my way out using this framework but nothing much happened. So moved back to codeigniter.